# Android: Looping through pictures and setting each as background

Tags: android

I have about 25 pictures in my `res/drawables`.
I want to loop through them, setting the next one as the background everytime the user hits a button on the screen.

Of course the drawables folder also has other pictures like droid icon etc which I don't want to use.

Cannot think of a good way of doing it. I thought of naming my pictures back1.jpg, back2.jpg... back25.jpg, and somehow looping through but this doesn't work. Can someone suggest a way/ sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three possibilities:

1)

Having a special folder in the assets res dir.

From the docs [raw/](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html):

> However, if you need access to
>   original file names and file
>   hierarchy, you might consider saving
>   some resources in the assets/
>   directory (instead of res/raw/). Files
>   in assets/ are not given a resource
>   ID, so you can read them only using
>   AssetManager.

2)

Have this static images in the `/res/drawable` folder and a small `HashMap` with the images that can be used as background.

3)

- Create an image.zip with all your backgrounds and place it on `/res/raw`
- On the first run extract to `/sdcard/yourapp/backgrounds/`
- Show only the images on that directory.

Depending on your app you can choose any of them.

Comment: Thansk for taking the time to answer. I am away from the work right now so cannot try these, will try your suggestions soon.

Comment: I used option number2, and it worked great. Instead of a hashmap, I used an int[] array which contained the resid of the images & looped through them.